# DataGridView Changing DataSource Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, datagridview

Basically when I create this DataGridView I have this code to fill it up

```
public void fillDataGrid(IQueryable<PatientInfo> patients) {

            dgvMyPatients.DataSource = patients;

            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_Last_Name"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_First_Name"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_Middle_Name"].DisplayIndex = 2;
            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_First_Name"].HeaderText = "First Name";
            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_Last_Name"].HeaderText = "Last Name";
            dgvMyPatients.Columns["Pat_Middle_Name"].HeaderText = "Middle Name";

        }

public IQueryable<PatientInfo> showMyPatients() {

            DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);

            var patientInfo = from patients in myDb.PatientInfos
                              where patients.Phy_ID == physcianID
                              select patients;

            return patientInfo;
        }
```

So when I create my Object I just do this

```
fillDataGrid(showMyPatients());
```

But When I click a button I want to change its contents to something like in this query

```
 private IQueryable<PatientInfo> searchPatient() {

        DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);
        var search = from myPatients in myDb.PatientInfos
                     where (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_First_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) ||
                     (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_Last_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) ||
                    (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_Middle_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
                     select myPatients;

        return search;
    }
```

Then when I click my button It will do this, but it is not updating the datagrid why is that?
    fillDataGrid(searchPatient());

Comment: Call 'dgvMyPatients.Refresh' after updating the datasource

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, after searched and tested a while, finally found the solution:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column One");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item1" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item2" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Item3.3" });

        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

`AutoGenerateColumns` needs be `true`, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead if doing

```
DataSource = null
```

its better to refresh the currency manager, given IQueryable returns CurrencyManager:

```
 (dgvMyPatients.BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource] as CurrencyManager).Refresh();
```

[CurrencyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx)

[CurrencyManager.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.refresh.aspx)

Comment: it is still not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = patients;
```

To

```
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = typeof(List<>);
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = patients.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

For one, you could try setting:

```
DataSource = null;
```

before updating it. I'd personally recommend using BindingList for binding your data to a dataGridView. This way, you don't have to change dataSource - only the data contained in it. It's used like this:

```
BindingList<PatientInfo> data = new BindingList<PatientInfo>();
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = data;

...
public void fillDataGrid(IQueryable<PatientInfo> patients)
{
    data.Clear();
    data.AddRange(patients);
}
```

Also, you wouldn't need to feed datagrid schema each time you update a source.

**UPDATE**

Working sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<SomeClass> _data = new BindingList<SomeClass>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _data;
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "1", Second = "1", Third = "1" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "2", Second = "2", Third = "2" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "3", Second = "3", Third = "3" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "4", Second = "4", Third = "4" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "5", Second = "5", Third = "5" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "6", Second = "6", Third = "6" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "7", Second = "7", Third = "7" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "8", Second = "8", Third = "8" });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _data.Clear();
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "11", Second = "11", Third = "11" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "21", Second = "21", Third = "21" });
        _data.Add(new SomeClass() { First = "31", Second = "31", Third = "31" });
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Third { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: will that work even if I have different queries because I have two different queries.

Comment: If all your queries return PatientInfo, then yes - that's the whole point. Your data container is fixed, only the data is changed.

Comment: Seems like BindingList hasn't got AddRange function - only Add, so you'd need to manually loop over enumeration of patients and add every one to bindingList. Refer to the following article for more info on BindingList: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

Comment: I tried doing the guidlines in the link you've provided me it seems that it is not working