# WinForms Display datagridview object in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have several datagridview objects saved in a global dictionary. I want  to find a specific datagridview object and display it in a datagridview. Everything seems to work exept for the actual display.
Here is the code that is suppost to display

```
if (seznamPodatkov.ContainsKey(tn.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = seznamPodatkov[tn.Text];

            }
```

Maybe I'm supposed to use the databind, but I don't know how to use it with many datagrid object, from which I get the right one.

Edit:
This code below saves datagridview objects, which should be later restored and displayed. The datagridview changes depending on a treeview, if a node with childs is clicked, then first is checked if a gridview from this parent node already exists. If it does, it should display that datagrid from dictionary, if not, it makes a new one and saves it to dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<string, DataGridView> seznamPodatkov;  

  if (tree1.SelectedNode == null) return;
            if(tree1.SelectedNode.GetNodeCount(false) > 0)
            {
                if (seznamPodatkov.ContainsKey(tree1.SelectedNode.Text))                              
                {
                    seznamPodatkov[tree1.SelectedNode.Text] = dataGridView1;
                }
                else seznamPodatkov.Add(tree1.SelectedNode.Text, dataGridView1);
            }

private void tree1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)                  
        {
            TreeNode tn = tree1.SelectedNode;
            if (tn == null) return;
            if (tn.GetNodeCount(false) > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

                if (seznamPodatkov.ContainsKey(tn.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = seznamPodatkov[tn.Text];

                }
                else
                {
                    dataFill(tn);


                }
                dataGridView1.Show();

            }
            else dataGridView1.Hide();
        }
```

Edit:

I made some slight progress. I tried it like this:

```
      DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.Columns.Add("something", "something");
        dgv.Columns.Add("something", "something");
        dgv.Columns.Add("something", "something");

        dataGridView1 = dgv;
```

datagridView1 seems to get the dvg columns, as I checked it with debugger. I have no idea if this is even correct or not, because the dataGridView1 still doesn't display the table in forms.

Comment: It Isn't clear what your asking.. Find data in the dictionary? Add datagrid dynamically?

Comment: your provided information is not sufficient. Please share your stuff so that we can understand and then help you

Comment: I want to add data to datagridview in forms from a datagridview object, that comes from a dictionary

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>` instead of `Dictionary<string, DataGridView>`.

Comment: I tried converting a dataGridView into DataTable by casting with no success. Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. First I thought that it's that simple: dgv = dgv1 but it's not.

Here is a test code that worked perferctly:

```
 Dictionary<string, DataGridView> dic;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView2.Columns.Add("nekaj", "nekaj");
        dataGridView2.Columns.Add("nekaj", "nekaj");
        dataGridView2.Columns.Add("nekaj", "nekaj");
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add("1", "2", "3");
        dic = new Dictionary<string, DataGridView>();
        dic.Add("test", dataGridView2);

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach(DataGridViewColumn columns in dic["test"].Columns)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columns.Name, columns.HeaderText);
        }

        foreach(DataGridViewRow rows in dic["test"].Rows)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();


          foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in rows.Cells)
            {
                list.Add(cell.Value);
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle things differently when I have such a need.  I use a custom `TabControl` that supports hiding the tabs, and couple that with a `TreeView` whose selection event controls which tab page is displayed.

This provides the illusion of one view that switches with the tree selection, while in reality you would have multiple, separate controls on the form.  This would allow you to do away with the `Dictionary` and simply bind each `DataGridView` directly to its data source.

Comment: That would be a great solution. The thing is, the datagridview is already in a tab control, thus would be too complicated to manage. Is there no simple way to get a datagridview object displayed in a datagridview?

Comment: I've never attempted what you are doing.  But perhaps the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957931/datagridview-changing-datasource-dynamically) will provide some assistance.

Comment: I would say 'no' to the simple way question. A DataGridView cell is not a container that can host controls as far as I know. You might be able to dynamically add DGV controls to a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: So to make it clear. There is no simple way to save a datagridview content to an object to later load it back to the datagridview? This seems odd

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even sure what your code is meant to do.  You are attempting to set the entire `DataGridView` instance to its own `DataSource` member.  Now _that_ is odd.  If you want to save the source, then do that.  If you want the instances, then you're going about it all wrong.  I think you should step back and consider what you're doing before you try to just _fix it_.

Comment: Allright. Let me explain it more clearly. I have a datagridview, that is showing several tables on click. For now every time a table is "called", it generates a new table(add row,column...). The user adds data to the cells. After another table is selected/created, the current one(or it's data) should be saved and retrieved when the same one is called later. The tables also vary in row/column count.

Comment: All of this may just be too broad for the SO format.  I don't know how you "call" tables, or what that even means.  If your DGV already shows "several tables" then why the save and restore?  But my basic point was what do you expect this line to do:  `dataGridView1.DataSource = seznamPodatkov[tn.Text];`?  It appears that the dictionary contains `DataGridView` instance(s), and not _data sources_.  You're assigning to the `DataSource`, not a full instance of a view.

Comment: There is just one dataGridView, that changes when needed. I attempted to save the dataGridView objects to a dictionary to later retrieve them and load them into dataGridView to display it.